# lockCanvas unlockCanvasAndPostm Camera.setPreviewDisplay

Tags: android, c++, camera, java-native-interface

I try to Draw in the same surface that the camera will draw it self later, by using lock and unlock.
the strange thing is that the try to lock succeed, but after the call unlockCanvasAndPost() the mCamera.setPreviewDisplay() throw error "setPreviewDisplay failed".

> Without calling lockCanvas() and unlockCanvasAndPost() the mCamera.setPreviewDisplay() work and i get my display.(running in android 4.1.1 compile with api 17)
>
> Remarque:(running in android 4.0.4 compile with api 17) sometimes run and only
>   if i lock and unlock using java, and not work using lock and unlock
>   from jni c/c++(ANativeWindow_lock() and ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost()).

but let's discuss only the java solution and why calling lockCanvas() and unlockCanvasAndPost() prevent the camera from working:

```
 mCamera=Camera.open();
        try {

            Canvas can;
            can = imageView.getHolder().getSurface().lockCanvas(null);
            Log.d("", "Canvas successfully acquired "); 

            imageView.getHolder().getSurface().unlockCanvasAndPost(can);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(this.imageView.getHolder());      
        } catch (IOException e) {       
            Log.d("",e.getMessage());
        }  catch (OutOfResourcesException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback);
        mCamera.startPreview();
```